# Ethan, CPU miner, with stratum support

Tags: mining, ethminer, ethash, cpu, stratum

I am developing pool software for ethash coins. I use a private chain and pool software running on VMs so I need a CPU miner with stratum support that I can run on on my laptop VMs.
Currently I was an [ethminer fork](https://github.com/avatar-lavventura/ethminer.git) which lacks stratum support. Does anyone have, or know where I can DL one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tried to merge the stratum functionality (in the latest version) with the fork mentioned above, but gave up as it's too much work.

Ended up using a stratum proxy ([eth-proxy](https://github.com/rodneymo/eth-proxy)) and that solved my problem